# XPath query for attribute not starting with another attribute

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to find all people with a displayName that does not start with their preferredName.

e.g.

```
<people>
  <person displayName="first1 last2" firstName="first1" lastName="last1" preferredName="preferred1" />
  <person displayName="preferred2 last2" firstName="first2" lastName="last2" preferredName="preferred2" />
</people>
```

I'd like to filter for just the 1st person in this example list.

something like?

```
/person[not(starts-with(displayName, preferredName))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `@attribute_name` to reference attribute in XPath :

```
//person[not(starts-with(@displayName, @preferredName))]
```

Comment: Frustratingly, the software I'm using has a weird XPath implementation that doesn't permit this query :(